# Can 2 random variables say $X$ and $Y$ be indetically distributed but dependent (and let's assume $X \neq Y$)

Tags: probability, independence

Can 2 random variables say $X$ and $Y$ be indetically distributed (for example both  have the same normal distribution) but $dependant$ (and let's assume $X \neq Y$.)

Comment: What if they are symmetric around zero and $Y=-X$?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, let $X$ be $N(0,\sigma^2)$. Then $X=-X$ in distribution but of course they are dependent.